# Makings spaces between columns using grid layout

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with making spaces between grid elements. This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="col">Hello1</div>

        <div class="col">Hello2</div>

        <div class="col">Hello3</div>

        <div class="col">Hello4</div>

</div>
```

And this is my CSS code:

```
body {
    background-color: green;
}

.col {
    margin: 0 2vw;
    padding: 1vh 1vw;
}

.container {
    width: 80vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
    background-color: maroon;
}
```

I have used this layout before, and it has worked just fine, but for some reason this doesn`t work now. I want to make space between each of the four columns, and make that space the same colour of the background color (in this case green).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use grid gap for spacing and move the background color to grid item instead of grid container so you can see the gap:

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}

.col {
  padding: 1vh 1vw;
  background-color: maroon;
}

.container {
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap:2vw;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="col">Hello1</div>

  <div class="col">Hello2</div>

  <div class="col">Hello3</div>

  <div class="col">Hello4</div>

</div>
```